# store modal in variable and show on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to store a modal in a variable and then show the modal when a user clicks a button. I tried this but nothing happens when I click the button and there is no console error.

```
$( '.outlet' ).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var prodID = $(this).data('id');
        var modal = `
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    `;
         $(modal).show();
    });
```

Comment: Why do you want do this? You could put the modal fade on `hide` by default and then when you want active it, just `addClass` show or directly call to `show()` method. Simply!

Comment: The reason I want to do this is because I actually want to assign different data to a modal. This is just the shell.

Comment: Ok, then you have to create two modals and alternate the state of each of them..

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by create two manners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind the `modal` to the DOM, to make it visible. In your code the HTML of your `modal`variable is not in the DOM, and that's why it is not displayed.

like show here:

`$("body").before(modal).show();`

***Althought you won't need `show()`since your attaching the HTML to the DOM with the `before`function (except it the HTML code has a style property set to `display:none` or you want a animation or ...).***

Here the working example. *I added some HTML to make the Example run.*

```js
$( '.outlet' ).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var prodID = $(this).data('id');
        var modal = `
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    `;
                    console.info("IN THE CLICK FUNCTION");
         $("body").before(modal);
         $(".modal").show();
   
    });
```

```css
.modal { 
margin:50px;
position: fixed; 
top: 0; 
right: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
left: 0; 
z-index: 99; 
display: none; 
overflow: hidden; 
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
outline: 0; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<button class="outlet">test</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works on your snippet but for some reason doesn't actually work on my webpage. The modal does not display.

Comment: you have to add the HTML-Code in the modal variable to the DOM, or it won't be displayed `$("body").before(modal).show();`

Comment: I have copied and pasted your exact code and it still won't work? Not sure what I am missing..

Comment: does your code enter the `click` function? does your code have an `body` tag? ... can you post some part of your HTML?

Comment: @user8463989 I updated my code, now if the `click`event is fired there is an output in the console. and the modal - HTML- Code is added, before the button. _Just to be sure that the selected element exists_. Could you try this?

Comment: Okay, for starters I tried your new code and the message pops up in the console, so that is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171932/discussion-between-user8463989-and-winner-joiner).